# Infinite loop in graph function implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to write a function `int within(Graph g, Vertex s, int d, Vertex *vs)`. The function takes a `Graph g, Vertex s (source vertex), int d (an upper bound on distance), a pointer to array of vertices Vertex *vs (note, Vertex is typedef int)`. This function is supposed to find all vertices that are a distance of less than or equal to `d` from the source `s`. It stores all such vertices in the `vs[]` array which is passed into the function as a pointer. The function returns the number of elements in `vs[]`.

[Examples of vertices that would be produced for various calls to the within() function:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rKkL.png)

**Problem**

I've implemented the function as you can see below. The only function which within() calls is findPath(), which is also shown below. However, for some reason, there is an infinite loop here:

```
     for(v = i; v != s; v = path[v]){
        count++;     //HERE IS THE INFINITE LOOP
     }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to count the number of edges from the source vertex (s) to the current vertex (v).

---

within() function

```
// Find all vertices which are <= d edges from v
int within(Graph g, Vertex s, int d, Vertex *vs)
{
   int i;

   //distance from current vertex to source vertex 
   int distance = 0; 

   //index to count number of elements in vs[]
   int vsIndex = 0;

   //for each vertex in the graph
   for(i=0; i<g->nV; i++){

      //make sure current vertex is not the source vertex
      if(i != s){

         //find path from current vertex to source vertex
         findPath(g, s, i);

         //compute distance from current to source vertex
         Vertex v; 
         for(v = i; v != s; v = path[v]){
            count++;     //HERE IS THE INFINITE LOOP
         }

         */if distance from current to source is less than or equal to d,
         add current vertex to vs[] array and increment vsIndex.
         /*
         if(count <= d){
            vs[vsIndex++] = i;
         }
         //reset distance for next vertex to be checked
         count = 0;
      }
   }

   return vsIndex;
}
```

The file which it's part of

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Stack.h"

// graph representation (adjacency matrix)
typedef struct GraphRep {
   int   nV;    // #vertices
   int   nE;    // #edges
   int **edges; // matrix of booleans
} GraphRep;

// - these variables are used by various algorithms
static int *visited; // array [0//nV-1] of seen vertices
static int *path;    // array [0..V-1] of vertices in path

void findPath(Graph g, Vertex src, Vertex dest)
{
   int i;
   // array of "been visited" flags
   for (i = 0; i < g->nV; i++) visited[i] = 0;
   // array of path predecessor vertices
   Queue q = newQueue();
   QueueJoin(q, src); visited[src] = 1;
   int isFound = 0;
   while (!QueueIsEmpty(q) && !isFound) {
      Vertex y, x = QueueLeave(q);
      for (y = 0; y < g->nV; y++) {
         if (!g->edges[x][y]) continue;
         path[y] = x;
         if (y == dest) { isFound = 1; break; }
         if (!visited[y]) {
            QueueJoin(q, y);
            visited[y] = 1;
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Obviously, the starting node isn't inserted into the path correctly. I cannot reproduce that (does your queue implementation work?), but that's where to start when debugging this. I think that `visited` and `path` should be members of the graph struct, not global arrays. Finally, I think that you should use a breadth-first search here instead of finding the paths for all vertex-vertex combos. In other words, `within` should look similar to `findPath`.

Comment: I can't see whole program but i would say that you have many loops in your graph also so when you visit nodes without storing them in a seperate array you can keep looping depending on how you implement algorithm , try to look if that's the case

Comment: @LuaiGhunim The problem is definitely with the path[] array. In some cases it gets stuck in an infinite loop. The frustrating thing is that I don't actually have to implement any algorithm from scratch since I'm given 6 function prototypes to use for this task (I decided to just use `findPath()` as shown above). I simply need to complete the task given haha!